# error overloaded method value foreach with alternatives in spark

Tags: foreach, apache-spark-sql

I am facing the error while running the below code. I want to show the output of count. My approach may be wrong. for example "country India count 4". So can anyone please let me know the correct approach.

```
val surveyrawDF = getSurveyDF(spark,args(0))
val selectDF = CountbyCountry(surveyrawDF)

val count = selectDF.foreach(row => "country :" + row.getString(0) + "count :" + row.getLong(1))

logger.info("Finished Hello Spark")
spark.stop()

}

 def CountbyCountry(SurveyDF:DataFrame): DataFrame = {
 SurveyDF.where(conditionExpr = "Age < 40").select(col = "Age", cols = "Gender","Country","State")
 .groupBy(col1 = "Country")
 .count()
}
```

It is showing the below error.

Error:(28, 14) overloaded method value foreach with alternatives:
(func: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ForeachFunction[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])Unit 
(f: org.apache.spark.sql.Row => Unit)Unit
cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Row => String)
selectDF.foreach(row => {"country :" + row.getString(0) + "count :" + row.getLong(1)})

Comment: I think this answer covers this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137538/overloaded-method-foreachbatch-with-alternatives