# Overloaded method foreachBatch with alternatives

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to serialize a json file to parquet format. I have this error :

> Error:(34, 25) overloaded method foreachBatch with alternatives:
> (function: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction2[org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],java.lang.Long])org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] 
> (function: (org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row], scala.Long) => Unit)org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
> cannot be applied to ((org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, scala.Long) => org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)
> askDF.writeStream.foreachBatch { (askDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>

And here is my code :

```
package fr.fdj
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType}


object serialize {

  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[1]")
    .appName("serialize")
    .getOrCreate()


  def main(args : Array[String]) {

  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  //schema definition
  val mySchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("Species", StringType, true),
    StructField("Race", StringType, true),
    StructField("Color", StringType, true),
    StructField("Age", IntegerType, true)
  ))

  val askDF = spark
  .readStream
  .format("json")
  .option("header", "true")
  .schema(mySchema)
  .load("/src/main/scala/file.json")

  askDF.writeStream.foreachBatch { (askDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
    askDF.persist()
    askDF.write.parquet("/src/main/scala/file.json")
    askDF.unpersist()
  }.start().awaitTermination()


  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a solution or an alternative for the function foreachBatch() ?

Comment: do you really need structured streaming here?

Answer (score 16):

I suppose you are using Scala 2.12.

Due to some changes in Scala 2.12, the method DataStreamWriter.foreachBatch requires some updates on the code, otherwise this ambiguity happens.

You can check Both foreachBatch methods here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/DataStreamWriter.html

I guess you could user scala 2.11 instead, or check the link, where the issue has been addressed: https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/7.0.html

In your code, you could try this:

```
def myFunc( askDF:DataFrame, batchID:Long ) : Unit = {
    askDF.persist()
    askDF.write.parquet("/src/main/scala/file.json")
    askDF.unpersist()
}
askDF.writeStream.foreachBatch(myFunc _).start().awaitTermination()
```

Comment: I ran into this issue when migrating from Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11 to Spark 3.0.1, Scala 2.12. Moving everything in my `.foreachBatch{...}` out to it's own method 100% solved my problem. Thank you! Can you elaborate on "Due to some changes in Scala 2.12"?

Comment: Found this as a potential explanation: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26132?focusedCommentId=17178019&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-17178019

Comment: what does the syntax `myFunc _` mean?  I know `myFunc(_, _)`.

Answer (score 3):

Return unit from function in `foreach` block by adding () at the end. Adding () at the last of inline function changes the method signature and hence the ambiguity in function is resolved

```
 askDF.writeStream.foreachBatch { (askDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
    askDF.persist()
    askDF.write.parquet("/src/main/scala/file.json")
    askDF.unpersist()
    ()
  }.start().awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This worked, but can you explain how the method signature changed? We're upgrading from Scala 2.11 to 2.12, could that be why?

Comment: yes this is due to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

As [@jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407161/jeremy) points out, there is a Spark compatibility version issue. The best solution that I could find is described below:

Create one variable with the function with the type and return explicitly.

```scala
val myFunc = (DataFrame, Long) => Unit = 
  (askDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {
    askDF.persist()
    askDF.write.parquet("/src/main/scala/file.json")
    askDF.unpersist()
  }
```

Use this new variable into the foreachBatch method

```scala
askDF
 .writeStream
 .foreachBatch(myFunc)
 .start()
 .awaitTermination()
```